# database Django on jython

Tags: database, django, jython-2.5

please i need help connecting database with jython on django and help me with the server when i put jython manage.py runserver the server don´t run

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'doj.backends.zxjdbc.sqlite3',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'tanagraweb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

and django throw this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 47, in <module>
    @python_2_unicode_compatible
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\jython2.7b3\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

i research and found that is the connector of mysql but i don´t know why this does´t work
if anyone has a project in jython on django i will be so much gratefull this is too hard

Answer (score 0):

Although `MySQLdb` is the most widely used MySql library among the Python/Django community, you can't use it because Jython does not work with C extensions.

To use Jython with Django, you need to install  [django-jython](http://pythonhosted.org//django-jython/index.html)  and set the db backend to `'ENGINE': 'doj.db.backends.mysql'`

This is documented in the official doc [Running Django on Jython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/)

Comment: i have tried this but does´t work, 
'ENGINE': 'doj.backends.zxjdbc.sqlite3' the error is django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading SQLite3 JDBC driver: No module named sqlite
maybe is the classpath i don´t know why

Answer (score 0):

1. Install pymysql with "pip install pymysql"
2. Add the following to your manage.py file:

`import pymysql`

`pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()`

3. In your DATABASES setting, use:

`ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',`